# Steps to follow before feeding a time series dataset in to neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network, forecast, mlp

Hi I'm having a time series dataset as below.

[image]

When it is plotted this is what I recognized.

[image]

I'm asked to forecast time series in this dataset. But I'm not sure on what are the preprocessing steps I need to be done, before feeding it to NN. Do I need to to input stationary data? Because in other models like ARIMA, SAMIRMA there are such steps.

1. How the data need to be preprocessed?
2. Can neuralnet R function for MLP used for this, because I was asked to use it?
3. When the pattern is seen, there are seasonal effects. How to use them.

Kindly help. What I need is a basic idea on areas that I need to focus on and what are the steps that I need to follow. Looking forward for your kind ideas as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in general time-series forecasting in R, [Rob Hyndman](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima.html) is the way to go. For his neural networks chapter, see [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/nnetar.html)

```
fit <- nnetar(sunspotarea, lambda=0)
autoplot(forecast(fit,h=30))
```

[image: hyndman]

For a more in-depth analysis of the Neural Network capabilities in R with the Keras / tensorflow packages, Francois Chollet's [book](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-r) should be the best source.

I know for a fact that it contains a chapter on time-series forecasting using RNN's.

Finally, h2o.ai is a good resource as well, they have an R package and [this](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/time-series.html) is some documentation on how to approach time series forecasting. Not sure if they did it specifically with NN's but their package definitely has this capability.

[image: h2o]

See the [h2o package doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf). For example, their `h2o.deeplearning` function builds a Deep Neural Network model using CPUs.

Comment: Hi.... I was asked only to use Neural Network

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: Thank you. I will look into them :)